# How do we update without removing field of state? (in React / JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How do we update without removing field of state?

```
async componentDidMount() {
    let { get_financial_assessment } = await DAO.getFinancialAssessment()
    if( get_financial_assessment ) {
        this.setState(get_financial_assessment); <- something with prevState...
    } else {
        // To-Do: Show the error page.
        console.log('You must login to see this page');
    }
}
```

Here is state

```
state = {
    income_source: '',
    employment_status: '',
    employment_industry: '',
    occupation: '',
    source_of_wealth: '',
    education_level: '',
    net_income: '',
    estimated_worth: '',
    account_turnover: '',
}
```

If we get `get_financial_assessment` as `{}`, the state currently gets updated as `{}`. :(

How can we prevent this?

**UPDATE** Sample Input

```
{
    account_turnover: "$25,000 - $50,000",
    cfd_score: 0, <- see this is extra field and this is unintentionally added to our state.
    education_level: "Secondary",
    employment_industry: ...

    ...
}
```

After `setState`, `state` will keep the same fields as I specified in `state` and update its values for each corresponding field.

Problem

1. sometimes the json data doesn't have required field and remove the field in `state`.
2. there is an extra field and it's being added to our `state`

Comment: You should make the API call in componentWillMount()

Comment: @JohnBeak - While answering I have assumed that when you say `{}` it means an empty object with no keys. Is it correct? If no, please clarify

Comment: exactly!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the question there can be 2 cases

**1. Object with all values being ''**

To check for an object with all keys as '', you will have to update your code to following

```
if( get_financial_assessment && Object.values(get_financial_assessment).every(v => v !== '')) {
   this.setState(get_financial_assessment); 
} else {
    // To-Do: Show the error page.
    console.log('You must login to see this page');
}
```

**2. Empty Object (No keys)**

Empty object `{}` does not evaluate to false, hence you will have to update your if statement to check for an empty object like following

```
if( get_financial_assessment && Object.keys(get_financial_assessment).length) {
   this.setState(get_financial_assessment); 
} else {
    // To-Do: Show the error page.
    console.log('You must login to see this page');
}
```

**EDIT**

You can prepare the object before hand and then set it using `setState` function.

```js
// original state
let state = {account_turnover: "$25,000 - $50,000",cfd_score: 0};
// Response with updated, missing and additional keys
let data = {cfd_score: 3,education_level: "Secondary",employment_industry: ""};

// Update the current state object and set using setState
Object.entries(state).forEach(([k,v]) => state[k] = data[k] ? data[k] : v);
console.log(state);
```

Comment: let's say get_financial_asessment gets {different_field: {}}. Can we check the matched fields and setState for each field. Thanks Thanks...!

Comment: It can be empty object or object with different extra fields.

Comment: @JohnBaek - Can you please give an example on object with different extra fields. Also, how do you figure it out as an extra field and what exactly is the desired output?

Comment: sure, hold on please

Comment: @JohnBaek - I have updated the answer. Please check.

Comment: @JohnBaek - I have simplified it further. Please check. I have updated the state object only. But you will still need to call setState because it automatically calls `ReactDOM.render()` - https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html

Comment: Nice Nice! tytytytyty

Comment: Welcome mate :)